# TeamCity connection to SVN fails - certificate rejected

Tags: svn, teamcity

I upgraded to TeamCity 10.0 this morning, and since the upgrade, TC cannot connect to my Subversion server.  The error I see is:

> Test connection failed in MyProject
>   Error connecting the specified URL:
>   svn: E200015: Server SSL certificate for 'https://svnserver:8443' rejected

There was no issue with the cert prior to upgrading to v10. Is there something I need to do now to allow TC to get to SVN over SSL?

Comment: I had just run into this issue and can't seem to find a work around. Did you get to find a solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

TeamCity 10.0 seems to have added an option to 'VCS Root' under 'Subversion Connection Settings' to 'Enable non-trusted SSL certificate'. Checking that option fixed those errors for me.

Comment: On the Build configuration page, the extended options are not anymore available unfortunately so I can't workaround the warning. I used the trick of philiplee (see below).

Answer (score 3):

I was able to correct this issue by telling SVN on the TeamCity server to accept the certificate permanently.  My solution will only work if you are using a Microsoft Windows Operating System and your TeamCity Service is running under a user account for the service rather than a machine account.

If you remotely connect via RDP to your TeamCity server as the user the TeamCity Service is running under and attempt to checkout anything from your SVN server, it should prompt you to ignore the bad certificate or accept the certificate permanently.  If you accept it permanently, your TC server immediately no longer throw an error with your SVN roots.  Note - I used TortoiseSVN to accomplish the checkout on the TeamCity server.

Comment: I did have services for both TeamCity Server and BuildAgent running under system local account - changing to service user account didn't help. Also run `svn list https://...` command to accept the certificate - didn't make difference either.

Comment: You have to login to the machine(teamcity server) as the user account you are running the service as, and then from there svn list or checkout and accept the certificate.

Comment: Thank you @philiplee, it worked for me. Much easier than modifying the cacerts file of TeamCity/JRE to make it know my certificate.